# Help Fix CQWP column alignment issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, column, content-query-web-part

I have a Content Query Web Part (CQWP) which is pulling in links from a specific Content Type that I have on all subsites. All I need is the link and all of the data to be displayed in 3 columns. I tried using the out of box function and although it works, it is not working correctly. The alignment for my three columns are not evenly spaced out and look strange. Is there any way to fix this?? Does anyone have any ideas of how to fix this issue?? If an XSL solution could you please help give me some code to work with?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: This (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447557%28v=office.14%29.aspx) link may help.

Comment: Thank you for the example from microsoft however it does not address the issue of multiple columns in the article. I know there are articles online but if an XSL solution like the link mentioned it would be nice to have some code to go with it

Answer (score 0):

Check if [this](https://williamwmy.wordpress.com/2013/04/16/presenting-content-query-web-part-items-in-a-html-table/) helps. You need to do changes in `ItemStyle.xsl`

```
<div class="description">
<td><xsl:value-of select="@ProjectProperty.Title" /> </td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@Status" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@Priority" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select='ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@DueDate),1044,1)' /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select='format-number(@PercentComplete,"#%")' /> </td>
</div>
```